# how to create a string in java to hold huge data without calling Arrays.copyOfRange to avoid out of memory error

Tags: java, string

the scenario here is I have to load nearly 350Mb data from file system into memory, doing sorting and give a final formatted string to the output file. to do that, I need to create sorting collections and a string builder for concatenation, and finally call the toString method to give the String object.

however, in this way, there will be a time spot when 3 copies of those huge data were in the memory and lead to out of memory exception.

is there any solution to work around instead of increase the heap size, using multiple string builders? because the restriction is there must be one string object holding the entire data and can not be split on cut into different string objects

Comment: *because the restriction is there must be one string object holding the entire data and can not be split on cut into different string objects* - You've gotto be kidding me. Who set this restriction?

Comment: @TheLostMind yea.. I know it's kidding. I come up with cutting data into multiple string objects and flush them into file so that GC can recover those objects. but, it's not permitted. I've been struggling for 2 days.

Comment: Please add more context (preferably some source code and input file excerpt). Are you sorting the file line-by-line or in some other manner? Does the resulting file contains just the reordered rows of input file or something more sofisticated should be done?

Answer (score 0):

ok. I figure it out. Just make all those sorting collections equal to null and force GC. This will do the trick.